# Does Reporting Services lock tables?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does SSRS lock the table when querying?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24091/does-ssrs-lock-the-table-when-querying)

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Reporting Services. Do the reports block other queries or are they executed in highly isolated transactions, such as a snapshot?

Next obvious question: Can reporting services produce deadlocks or timeouts in other queries as a result of locking tables for a long time?

Comment: For pessimistic isolation levels, unless you are using the Read Uncommitted transaction isolation level, then SSRS queries (to be treated as any other query) can and will issue locks on data.  As for what resource is locked (RID/key, page, table, etc.) all depends on specifics.

Comment: See @gbn's answer to a similar question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24091/does-ssrs-lock-the-table-when-querying/24094#24094

Comment: Thanks @Shark, I think the other answer solves my question then. I've flagged the question as duplicate then.

Answer (score -1):

FYI, unless specifically directed, all TSQL statements are presumed Snap-Shots.

1st Question:

- So Think of it as your SSRS is looking at your data as if it were a View/Select statement.

2nd Question:

- It could, pending on the volume of calculation (SSRS) and volume of users.  Think you would have to have well over 10% CPU/RAM utilization from SSRS and over 50% CPU/RAM utilization from general queries in order for you to notice an effect, albeit hardly noticeable (like 1-10 nSecs).

Comment: Not sure if I understand. "All TSQL statements are presumed snapshots"... Do you mean all statements in RS or everywhere?

Comment: "unless specifically directed, all TSQL statements are presumed Snap-Shots."  Are you insinuating that the default transaction isolation level in SQL Server is Snapshot Isolation?  In which case, that is not true.  It is Read Committed.

Comment: @DiegoJancic RS, if you mean RecordSets, are not TSQL.  Even though the Query results in a TSQL, they are two different view points pending on which end of the transaction your talking about.

Comment: @Shark Really then why are Batches only committed at the end, and not while it is happening?  If everything wasnt a SnapShot Isolation then you wouldnt need to Commit them at all.  Read Committed is a subset of SnapShot Isolation.  By definition a Snapshot is a view of data at the time of the query.

Comment: @CleanFill experience in supporting those environments.  You notice a bigger hit when your Service CPU Utilization hits around 75-80% utilization.

Comment: @GoldBishop with RS I mean Reporting Services. Regarding your answer to Shark, even if you might be literally correct, in your answer you're confusing the terms. What is called snapshot is a 'new' isolation level that includes row versioning and does not lock other queries.

Comment: `READ COMMITTED` has two modes (with snapshot isolation on, and with snapshot isolation off) -- see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx). In SQL Azure, read-committed snapshot is the default, but this question, AFAICT, asks about the standalone version, where snapshot isolation is off by default.

Comment: @DiegoJancic *nod*....Snapshot isnt technically new, since Access has been using it (in various forms) since 2000/2003'ish.  MS SQL's earliest implementation was really in 2005, even though 2000 has a ghost of an implementation (which was nasty).  Database Snapshots were fully implemented in 2008 with a more efficient form of Leaf Locks in 2008r2.  In my experience, if you wanted a lock you explicitly design the query with the syntax, otherwise leave the Locking mechanism open by default.

Comment: @GoldBishop You're talking about implicit and explicit transactions with your response to me.  I'm talking about transaction isolation levels.  And yes, you can have snapshot isolation but it is off by default.

Comment: @Shark but to not consider the Default settings when designing a query would be adding more resources that are unnecessary to your transactions.  Just making sure you understand that the Implicit (Default) settings can carry weight into how your server processes transactions and what locking mechanisms are/not set per transaction.  So to think of it as Explicit or Implicit is very important when it comes to Snapshot isolation.  Seeing the forest vs the Tree.